# Need help with prereform writing on a artefact

Tags: meaning, translation, kanji

My great uncle found this item on Okinawa prior to the end of WW2.  I have tried to find out what it says but have never been able to locate anything or anyone that is able to help since the writing appears to be from before reforms were made after WW2.

Any help would be appreciated as I have been searching for several years for answers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This clearly originally comprised four characters.  Two are clear, and two are very faded and nearly illegible.  Let's see what we can find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only make out the first three characters, read from top to bottom, then right to left:

- 渡満紀...

The last character appears to have 亻 as one component, but I can't quite make it out.

The first word 渡満 is read as [と]{to}[ま]{ma}[ん]{n}, and it means "crossing over (i.e. emigrating) to Manchuria", in reference to the Japanese colony established in Manchuria during the 1930s and early 1940s.  See also the [Manchukuo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchukuo) article on Wikipedia.

---

**UPDATE:** Looping back to this a bit late, what with the holidays and all the unfortunate hullabaloo in the US these days.

[User 7810](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/7810) (formerly Broccoli, currently Broken Laptop) commented with a compelling suggestion: handwritten forms, such as those on this cup, often exhibit a kind of slant to the lines, making it more likely that the last character here is 念.  See also their mock-up of what the whole four-character text may have looked like:

[image: Sample image of four-character text]

Thus, [Ragaroni](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/34142)'s suggested reconstruction is the most-likely contender:

- **渡満紀念**, literally "crossing to Manchuria commemoration", or in more natural English, "Commemorating the Move to Manchuria".

Note that this is a snippet of wartime text, and thus it might be viewed negatively in a modern context.

Comment: I'm going to guess 紀念, which would make the phrase mean something like "Commemorating the migration to Manchuria."

Comment: Also, translation requests without evidence of prior research are considered off topic for this board, so this question will probably be closed soon.

Comment: Hmm, ya, except the first character is clearly 紀, not 記 — wrong radical, 糸 instead of 言. Also, the second character appears to have the 人偏 radical, extending vertically along the left side clear to the bottom of the character. It’s the only halfway clearly visible part of that character.

Comment: Thank you for all the information.  I did see the warning about threads closing if it was just for translation, but still wanted to give it a shot.  I'm just a sped teacher with zero background in the Japanese language or writing so had no resources or connections to turn to.  Thank you again for all the help.

Comment: Yes, Eirikr is right about the typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Looking at possible compounds with 紀, how about 紀伝? Seems to fit the little bit we can see in the image...

Comment: @blutorange I wondered that too, but the 旧字体 of 伝 is 傳, which made me think it wouldn't have been used pre-reforms, but maybe it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I do support @Ragaroni's reading 渡満紀念. There is an alternate spelling 紀念 for 記念 which is practically obsoleted. See the note in: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A8%98%E5%BF%B5/

Comment: @brokenlaptop, it's tempting, but the character on the cup pretty plainly has 亻 on the left, and some element in the center that has left three horizontally parallel lines or dots, and then the additional stroke that finishes to the bottom right.  I'm not familiar with [any variant of 念](https://glyphwiki.org/wiki/u5ff5) that might leave behind the traces visible on the cup.

Comment: @blutorange, that seems close, but the meaning is off -- 紀伝 is "biography", which seems odd for this context; also, the three horizontally parallel strokes in the center don't fit the shape of either 伝 or 旧字体 shape 傳.  But perhaps I'm mis-seeing things there?

Comment: To add some extra context to the cup in case it would help more.  It was found during the Invasion of Okinawa during 1945 by my great uncle.  Story goes it the only thing left in one piece in a defensive position that had either been abandoned or destroyed by naval gunfire.  Unfortunately he passed years ago before I ever learned of this object, so no way to confirm the story or origin.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I mean, in handwriting, people often write 右上がり, so that characters look like this: https://imgur.com/a/C5MezNB

Comment: Also compare [this](https://page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp/jp/auction/s698503651). I believe this article is relevant [満蒙開拓移民](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BA%80%E8%92%99%E9%96%8B%E6%8B%93%E7%A7%BB%E6%B0%91).